# node-api.h problem, while configure build with node-gyp

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

here is the console after node-gyp configure build && node index.js

> - In file included from ../test.cc:1:0:
> - :0:26: error: expected initializer before ‘-’ token
> - /home/vir4un/.node-gyp/10.9.0/include/node/node_api.h:74:15: note: in definition of macro ‘NAPI_C_CTOR’
> - static void fn(void) **attribute**((constructor)); \
> - /home/vir4un/.node-gyp/10.9.0/include/node/node_api.h:104:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘NAPI_MODULE_X’    NAPI_MODULE_X(modname,
>     regfunc, NULL, 0)  // NOLINT (readability/null_usage)
> - ../test.cc:47:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘NAPI_MODULE’  NAPI_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Init)
> - ../test.cc:47:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME’  NAPI_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Init)

also

> - gyp ERR! build error
> - gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
> - gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
> - gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
> - gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:239:12)
> - gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-33-generic
> - gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "configure" "build"
> - gyp ERR! cwd /home/vir4un/app/tanya/app
> - gyp ERR! node -v v10.9.0
> - gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
> - gyp ERR! not ok

also here is debug log :

> 1. info it worked if it ends with ok
> 2. verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
> 3. info using npm@6.4.1
> 4. info using node@v10.9.0
> 5. verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
> 6. info lifecycle app@1.0.0~prestart: app@1.0.0
> 7. info lifecycle app@1.0.0~start: app@1.0.0
> 8. verbose lifecycle app@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
> 9. verbose lifecycle app@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/vir4un/app/tanya/app/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
> 10. verbose lifecycle app@1.0.0~start: CWD: /home/vir4un/app/tanya/app
> 11. silly lifecycle app@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'node-gyp configure build && node index.js' ]
> 12. silly lifecycle app@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
> 13. info lifecycle app@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
> 14. verbose stack Error: app@1.0.0 start: `node-gyp configure build && node index.js`
> 15. verbose stack Exit status 1
> 16. verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
> 17. verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
> 18. verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
> 19. verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
> 20. verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
> 21. verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:250:5)
> 22. verbose pkgid app@1.0.0
> 23. verbose cwd /home/vir4un/app/tanya/app
> 24. verbose Linux 4.15.0-33-generic
> 25. verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
> 26. verbose node v10.9.0
> 27. verbose npm  v6.4.1
> 28. error code ELIFECYCLE
> 29. error errno 1
> 30. error app@1.0.0 start: `node-gyp configure build && node index.js`
> 31. error Exit status 1
> 32. error Failed at the app@1.0.0 start script.
> 33. error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
> 34. verbose exit [ 1, true ]

here is test.cc :

> ```
> #include <node_api.h>
> ```
>
> napi_value MyFunction(napi_env env, napi_callback_info info) {
>   napi_status status;   size_t argc = 1;   int number = 0;   napi_value
>   argv[1];   status = napi_get_cb_info(env, info, &argc, argv, NULL,
>   NULL);
>
> if (status != napi_ok) {
>       napi_throw_error(env, NULL, "Failed to parse arguments");   }
>
> status = napi_get_value_int32(env, argv[0], &number);
>
> if (status != napi_ok) {
>       napi_throw_error(env, NULL, "Invalid number was passed as argument");   }   napi_value myNumber;   number = number * 2;   status
>   = napi_create_int32(env, number, &myNumber);
>
> if (status != napi_ok) {
>       napi_throw_error(env, NULL, "Unable to create return value");   }
>
> return myNumber; }
>
> napi_value Init(napi_env env, napi_value exports) {   napi_status
>   status;   napi_value fn;
>
> status = napi_create_function(env, NULL, 0, MyFunction, NULL, &fn); 
>   if (status != napi_ok) {
>       napi_throw_error(env, NULL, "Unable to wrap native function");   }
>
> status = napi_set_named_property(env, exports, "my_function", fn);
>   if (status != napi_ok) {
>       napi_throw_error(env, NULL, "Unable to populate exports");   }
>
> return exports; }
>
> NAPI_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Init)

// they said it is on node_api.h , i don't even edit the original file. it kill me inside.

Answer (score 1):

Mosy likely you used the incorrect symbol in the module name. Such `hello-world`. Symbol `-` is prohibited.